# How to loop over components object in the template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Usually we define in a Nuxt.js component something like this:

```
<script>
export default {
 components: {
    // components
  }
 data() {
   return {
     // key/value data
   }
 },
 methods: {
    // method definitions
 }
}
</script>
```

Is there a way to read the `components` object as we read `data()` and `methods` ?

This is because I have several components and I want to loop on them to refactor parts of my code.

Comment: Have you tried the exact same method you used to access `methods` ?

Comment: That is different, for methods, we just call the method we want in the template by `{{ methodName() }}`

Answer (score 2):

You can get Component data by using $options.
Try this.

```
created() {
      console.log(this.$options.components)
}
```

it returns an object, keys are the component names, values are the contructors.

codepen - https://codesandbox.io/s/yk9km5m0wv

Comment: Does not work (I tried it in different ways), but thank you

Comment: What do you see when you try that? @Begueradj , did you try in mounted?